# Where is the AxMSTSCLib library located?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I was reading a book "wpf4 unleashed by Adam Nathan" and saw an example about "Hosting the Terminal Services ActiveX control in a WPF Window". It has some code displayed and I figured out that I should do it.

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
    namespace HostingActiveX
    {
       public partial class Window1 : Window
       {
          AxMSTSCLib.AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting termServ;
        public Window1()
    {
InitializeComponent();
// Create the host and the ActiveX control
WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
termServ = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting();
// Add the ActiveX control to the host, and the host to the WPF panel
host.Child = termServ;
panel.Children.Add(host);
}
      void connectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        termServ.Server = serverBox.Text;
        termServ.Connect();
      }
     }
    }
```

and XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class=”HostingActiveX.Window1”
    xmlns=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation”
    xmlns:x=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml”
    Title=”Hosting the Terminal Services ActiveX Control”>
    <DockPanel Name=”panel” Margin=”10”>
    <StackPanel Margin=”0,0,0,10” DockPanel.Dock=”Top”      Orientation=”Horizontal”>
    <TextBox x:Name=”serverBox” Width=”180” Margin=”0,0,10,0”/>
    <Button x:Name=”connectButton” Click=”connectButton_Click”>Connect</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
    </Window>
```

But I can't find the reference for AxMSTSCLib. I added MSTSCLib, but It does not like it. Where can I find AxMSTSCLib?

Comment: I have one under  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Simulator\14.0\AxMSTSCLib.dll" but then I assume you did do a file search

Comment: It is not located anywhere, it is dynamically created.  Either by running aximp.exe or adding a reference to the ActiveX component.  Easiest: right-click the toolbar > Choose Items > COM Components tab > tick "Microsoft RDP Client Control".  Drop it on a form.

Comment: @BugFinder I have windows 7. But I did find that dll in the citrix folder... the scan was still running when I wrote this. Thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant I don't have Microsoft RDP Client Control under Com tab. I was able to find the dll under citrix app. But It's nice to know that you can create it.

Comment: Everybody has this, you didn't do it right somehow.  Not "Com tab".  Don't pick random files, they will not be there the next time or on another machine or will have the wrong version.  But what the heck, let the next guy sort it out, they did it to you.